# Java Encryption: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Tags: java, for-loop, encryption, switch-statement, case

I'm creating a program that will be both capable of encrypting and decrypting text. Currently, my encryption and decryption processes occur with CASE SWITCHES in order to avoid any overlapping/error in encryption. I feel as though this should be working. Essentially, the encryption works in the following manner: a FOR loop reads every character of a String input, and then turns it over to a CASE SWITCH to be replaced with a certain String. I am getting the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:541)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:350)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:888)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:955)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
    at OR_v5_12_5_16.main(OR_v5_12_5_16.java:161)

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Here is a slightly modified and shortened version of the code block. The real code block runs through all 26 uppercase characters and all 26 lowercase characters. Prior to the error message, the program appears to stall.

```
for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++){

    String txt_char = String.valueOf(txt.charAt(i));

        switch (txt_char){

            case "A":

                txt = txt.replaceFirst("A", "11110000"); 
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Post your code as a [mcve], and we might be able to help.  As it stands, we cannot provide effective help.

Comment: Please copy and paste code and logs. Don't use images in these cases.

Comment: @AJNeufeld It has been provided as of now

Comment: @sanastasiadis Fixed

Comment: Are you just "encrypting" letters as strings of 1's and 0's?  Or are you also encrypting the characters `'1'` and `'0'`?  If so, when your loop encounters the `'1'` or `'0'`, it will *again* expand all of that character, generating an infinite expansion.

Comment: @Kayaman You are wrong. If you put 26 replaceAll() together, they lap over one another. If "A" is replaced with "B", and the next replace method is replacing "B", then there is an error in the logic with encryption. Additionally, it wouldn't be much of an encryption if I showed everyone what every character meant. Hence my shortened version of the code. Also, I will admit that I caught my error in typing out my code and corrected it from replaceAll() to replaceFirst().

Comment: @AJNeufeld No, there are no numbers involved. I replaced the actual String replacement with a random array of fake binary code for an example. The actual code replaces a single character with a String. I have avoided infinite expansion as best as possible. If you see my reply to Kayaman I believe I discuss this.

Comment: @Kayaman First of all, if you cannot help then leave. Second, I also just told you that I have shortened my encryption and I have left out some processes involved in the encryption processes that I know are not causing the error message. Publicly displaying the entire encryption process defeats the purpose of developing an encryption. Thirdly, explain why my code does not prevent overlapping. It seems you are just here to bash code and be pretentious. As I said earlier, leave if you are not here to help.

Comment: No, you just fixed the question. The `replaceAll` call was wrong, and it looked like you were converting letters into binary digits. So don't complain if you post garbage and it's called out as garbage. It's still not a proper encryption though, so you might as well post the *real* code.

Comment: `replaceFirst()` is not even going to help if you have written out that character in a prior encrypted data segment.  With "AYE", if you replace character at index 0 ('A') with "EFG", you get "EFGYE".  When you eventually reach the final "E", `replaceFirst()` will replace the first character of the string, not the last character.

Comment: If you think it's not a real encryption, I'll just go ahead and post some and you can crack it in the next ten minutes. Okay? I've already created the same program in Python, I'm translating it to Java.

Comment: @AJNeufeld That is a good point, I knew I must have been missing something. So maybe I could do something like "A" is replaced with "EFG" and i += replacement_string.length()?

Comment: That would help, by avoiding reading an already encrypted character as if it were still the plain text.  But it doesn't help the problem that you can't target the "E" at a particular position in `txt` with `replaceFirst()`.

Comment: You do realize that cryptanalysis can handle a lot more complex encryptions than your [monoalphabetic substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). It's almost as weak as your question.

Comment: I don't know of any java environment where your code will cause a OOM unless `txt` is already almost as large as all the memory allocated to the JVM.

Comment: Just to further the OPs learning... What you are creating is an *encoding* and is not encryption.  It also relies on "security through obscurity" which is a big no no.  People crack these encodings with pencil and paper, they easily fall victim to frequency analysis and provide no actual security at all. Not to mention you are bloating 1 byte to 8 bytes. Using this where real security is required would not be smart.

Answer (score -1):

Your encryption code can be made much more efficient, by:

- pre-allocating the memory required for the result
- not converting single characters back into strings

Example:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(txt.length() * 8);

int len = txt.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    char ch = txt.charAt(i);

    switch (ch) {
        case 'A': result.append("11110000"); break;
        case 'B': result.append("10101010"); break;
        // ... etc ...
    }
}

txt = result.toString();
```

By not modifying the original `String` during the encryption, any chance of re-encryption of already encrypted data is also eliminated.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to give that a try! Thank you for your help!